# Mark a line with a color in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I would like to mark a certain line in my React component in green.

After searching for a way to do that, this is what I wrote:

```
     var transferDateElemet =  <tr>
                  <td>Date of transfer to organization </td>
                  <td style={{color: green,background: '#00CC00'}}>
                             {transferDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + (transferDate.getUTCMonth() +1 ) + "/" + transferDate.getUTCFullYear()}{transferDateExpected}
                  </td>
              </tr>;
```

Of course, it is written inside render().

I would like to get a suggestion of how to make it work. Also, if I did not supply enough details please let me know.

*This is the error I get:

```
Failed to compile.

EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\***\***\***\***\***\***\static\media\logo.ee7cd8ed.svg'


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add div in tr element.Try this:

```
<td style={{color: green,background: '#00CC00'}}>
{transferDate.getUTCDate() + "/" + (transferDate.getUTCMonth() +1 ) + "/" + transferDate.getUTCFullYear()}{transferDateExpected}
```

Edit:
For your problem, there are many reasons for this, so here are some options for you to try.

1. run *npm cache clean* and *npm install*
2. close editor software and open it again
3. if you are using windows, close node.js serve in back terminal and  close the window defender

Comment: didn't work. Should I import anything when I use style ? (I know it should built in with React). I added the error to my question so you can see it.

Comment: I have edit your answer and add some advices for you.

Comment: It's working man! All needed is just to put 'green' under quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

The color property makes the text color green. Is the text not changing to green? If not try using hex code and see if it works

Comment: Does is make the text green? I wanted the text to stay black but with a green marker over it. Anyway both doesn't happen.

Comment: For your use case you would want to use the html tag <mark> and use css to change the highlighted color ( it defaults to yellow highlight). Also dont surround div with mark tag.  Surround mark tag around the text you wanna highlight